# Flattening out Response File in R

Tags: r, nested-lists, purrr

I am fairly new to R and though I have read the r documentation and other questions i am still having issues with the concepts. Spotify's Track object is a list, which contains an inner list of artists on the track. I am trying to flatten the list down to the first artist in the list, but I dont know even the proper functions to use.

Basically from the below Songs object I would like to pull out the name, id, and first artist. I did it using a for loop and looping through each record, but i would like to know if there is a more elegant way to do it.

```
    Songs[[407]][c("name","id","artists")]
    $name
    [1] "Down Like This (feat. Tkay Maidza)"

    $id
    [1] "0DEbrObho3rzUFkaKLrpQA"

    $artists
    $artists[[1]]
    $artists[[1]]$external_urls
    $artists[[1]]$external_urls$spotify
    [1] "https://open.spotify.com/artist/3SwgftmsT5rVepCSSco3ZR"


    $artists[[1]]$href
    [1] "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/3SwgftmsT5rVepCSSco3ZR"

    $artists[[1]]$id
    [1] "3SwgftmsT5rVepCSSco3ZR"

    $artists[[1]]$name
    [1] "Motez"

    $artists[[1]]$type
    [1] "artist"

    $artists[[1]]$uri
    [1] "spotify:artist:3SwgftmsT5rVepCSSco3ZR"


    $artists[[2]]
    $artists[[2]]$external_urls
    $artists[[2]]$external_urls$spotify
    [1] "https://open.spotify.com/artist/1kMPdZQVdUhMDKDWOJM5iK"


    $artists[[2]]$href
    [1] "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/1kMPdZQVdUhMDKDWOJM5iK"

    $artists[[2]]$id
    [1] "1kMPdZQVdUhMDKDWOJM5iK"

    $artists[[2]]$name
    [1] "Tkay Maidza"

    $artists[[2]]$type
    [1] "artist"

    $artists[[2]]$uri
    [1] "spotify:artist:1kMPdZQVdUhMDKDWOJM5iK"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably write a simple function and then use `lapply`. Along the lines of:

```
songProcess <- function(song){
  name <- song$name
  id <- song$id
  fistArtist <- song$artists[[1]]$name
  return(c(name,id,firstArtist))
}
parsed <- lapply(Songs,songProcess)
```

`parsed` will be a list of 3-element vectors of the name, id, and first artist on the song.

Comment: No prob! You should use the check mark to mark the question as answered if you consider your problem solved :-)